# Setting up a Google Analytics Campaign

Tags: google-analytics

I will be doing a bunch of things to give one of my projects (main app) a big initial push for which I will be building a few small Facebook apps which will help in promoting the main apps. Traffic from these apps need to be tracked individually.

My main app will be posting on the walls when the user needs to be notified. Traffic from these posts need to be tracked.

Traffic from emails sent by the main app need to be tracked, like different types of email.

I need to track all of these & possibly a couple of more but I need to be sure that I build my campaign URLs correctly as I won't get another chance to fix it.

Correct me where I am wrong:

```
Campaign Name: Launch
Campaign Medium: Email
Campaign Source: Type1 or Type2 (I can break it down for different types of email, right?)
```

For apps:

```
Campaign Name: Launch
Campaign Medium: Apps
Campaign Source: App1 or App2 (I can break it down here for different apps, right?)
```

What if I want to track two different links within a single email or a single app? Any way of tracking them individually too but still keeping to track them as one because tracking them as one makes more sense for me.

Campaign Term & Campaign content is irrelevant in my case, or I can/should use them for something?

And I will also be tracking traffic of different apps. Should I do more?

Let me know if my scenario wasn't clear enough & I need to explain more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you can use the five campaign variables available to you for whatever you want.

However, the way you used the three main variables in your examples is fine and follows Google's advice. It's your launch campaign, so that's a fitting value for Campaign Name, the Campaign Medium is the type of source and Campaign Source is supposed to be the actual source. That's all fine.

If you need to track additional information, that's what the two remaining variables should be used for. If you have two different links in your email, I'd suggest using the Campaign Content for that information. It's usually meant for tracking two campaign items that differ only by their content (e.g. blue button vs. red button in a display ad), so it's reasonably suitable for your case.

Make sure you use the same values every time (it's case sensitive), otherwise your data in Analytics will be all messy.